# c# Pegar texto e inserir em cima da imagem

Tags: c#, inserir, picturebox, texto

Eu tenho uma pictureBox, e preciso que o usuario consiga fazer "marcações" na imagem. Por exemplo, a imagem é um corpo humano, preciso que o usuário ao clicar na foto onde fica o braço, por exemplo, fique uma setinha desenhada escrito "braço". Ao clicar na perna, apareça uma setinha aonde ele clicou e um texto encima escrito "perna" e assim por diante.

Já tenho varios checkboxes no form, onde cada um já tem todos os textos que devem aparecer na imagem, como braço, pernas, cabeça. Precisaria de um jeito de pegar esse `checkbox.Text` ao clicar no checkbox, e inserir esse texto na foto, exatamente onde o usuario clicou.

E preciso que isso tudo fique salvo no banco, ou seja, qndo ele clicar em salvar, essas marcações na foto tmb tem q serem salvas.

Eu até o momento estava usando o `CreateGraphics`() e `DrawLine`(), para o usuario circular as partes do corpo, porem, não salva os riscos desenhados em cima da foto, e fica muito limitado apenas circular com o drawline, queria um texto na foto.

É possivel? Nem sei como pesquisar melhor sobre isso. Alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: ainda com o Graphics, tem o DrawString, e também é com eles que você irá salvar os desenhos, vou tentar achar um código que tenho aqui

Comment: Mas onde está o seu problema? Não consegue salvar as imagens no banco de dados? Não consegue obter a posição do mouse? Deixe mais claro o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Quero inserir um texto (a propriedade text do checkbox) em cima de uma imagem no lugar que o usuario clicar. Se ele clicar no checkbox "braço", depois na foto aonde fica o braço, quero q apareça escrito "braço" aonde ele clicou. E no final de tudo, essa imagem com essas marcaçoes ser salva no banco, como se esses textos fossem parte da imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa pegar os Graphics da imagem, e não dos controles ou form:

```
var g =  Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
```

Este é um método que utilizo para desenhar um círculo sobre a imagem:

```
    private void Circulo(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(pic1.Image);
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(panelColor.BackColor);
        Pen p = new Pen(br);
        p.Width = (float)tam;

        int W = e.Location.X - mouseDownPosition.X;
        int H = e.Location.Y - mouseDownPosition.Y;
        if (W > 0 && H > 0)
            g.DrawEllipse(p, mouseDownPosition.X, mouseDownPosition.Y, W, H);
        else if (W > 0 && H < 0)
        {
            H *= -1;
            g.DrawEllipse(p, mouseDownPosition.X, e.Location.Y, W, H);
        }
        else if (W < 0 && H > 0)
        {
            W *= -1;
            g.DrawEllipse(p, e.Location.X, mouseDownPosition.Y, W, H);
        }
        else
        {
            W *= -1;
            H *= -1;
            g.DrawEllipse(p, e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, W, H);
        }

        RefreshPictureBox();
        g.Dispose();
        p.Dispose();
        br.Dispose();
    }
```

e para chama-lo:

```
        private void pictureBoxView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
                Circulo(e);
        }
```

A Parte de escrever o texto na imagem:

```
g.DrawString("SEU TEXTO", new Font("Verdana", 10F, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Red, new PointF(0, 0));
```

onde `g` é o objeto Graphics, claro

Comment: O texto com drawstring deu certo, mas o elipse nao ficou transparente no fundo, ficou tudo preto, Mas de qualquer forma, metade do problema ja foi, muito obrigado meu amigo pela luz q deu.

Comment: não se esqueça de marcar como resposta, mas deve ter algo errado, porque o elipse preenchido seria feito com o FillEllipse e não DrawEllipse, verifique se está assim

Comment: Me surgiu uma duvida, caso o usuario clique por exemplo na perna ao invez do braço, como deletar o texto que o drawstring fez? existe uma borracha??

Comment: tem como, mas, basicamente você cria uma imagem por cima da outra para isso, em várias camadas, aí dá inclusive pra fazer um Ctrl Z. Esse código fiz há muito tempo, e utilizava apenas 3 camadas. Se quiser posso te passar o código do Form todo, chama no chat

Comment: Oi @Rovann Linhalis , gostaria do codigo sim, mas nao sei como usa o chat daqui.